# Extracting data from raster layers in R

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I'm trying to understand how I can extract data from a raster layer in R.

I've downloaded the [tavg 10m data set](http://www.worldclim.org/current) and I would like to extract the mean temperature of a location.

My approach so far is to read the layer for January and extract the mean temperature for Frankfurt:

```
layer.jan <- raster("data/tmean_10m_bil/tmean1.bil")
layer.jan <- layer.jan/10

# get value for Frankfurt
loc <- as.data.frame(c(50.114928, 8.702152))
loc <- coordinates(loc)
temp <- extract(layer.jan, matrix(loc, ncol = 2))
```

This, however returns the value **23.5**, which is unfortunately not the mean temperature in Frankfurt in January.

I've tried to understand the input values from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144623/extracting-point-information-from-raster-in-r) example, but I don't really get how these values map to longitude / latitude coordinates.

Please assume that I know only very little about GIS data, it's my first attempt to explore this area.

Comment: I think you have longitude and latitude mixed up here. raster::extract(x,y) requires that the coordinates are in the order of (longitude, latitude).

Comment: Yesss, that sounds right! If I switch the values, I get a mean temperature of 0,7. That sounds more realistic. Great!